# Button turns white after pressing. ( iOS ) Back to normal after refresh

Tags: ios, xcode

Using Xcode 4.3.3

After pushing button in App to dial out, it switches to the phone to dial out. Upon returning to the app the dial out button is white out, goes back to normal after refresh.

The same thing happens when another button is pushed for email or text. It appears that it only happens when leaving the current app to do something outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

What about using

```
button.selected = NO
```

If your still not satisfied you might want to add it to the

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

in the app delegate

to create a pointer to the button create

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIButton * button
```

in the .m add

```
@synthersize button;
```

Then in Interface builder you need to link up the IBOutlet with the button by holding control and dragging from the ViewContrtoller Icon

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your suggestion.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your suggestion. I added "@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button;" to the appdelegate.h. Then "@synthesize button = _button;" in the delegate.m, and "button.selected = NO" after the open curly brace after "- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application". If that's you suggestion, I tried it and it did not work. Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I ve added some more details, forgive me if i stated the obvious. Let me know if there is anything else you need to know GC